# What is the etymology of 斥

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin, history

Learning the word 斥 chì to blame,to reprimand, to expel, (of territory) to expand. What is the etymology and how it is to blame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「斥」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese): **/*tʰAk/**) was originally a character formed by modifying [「宅」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=369) (**/*m-tˤak/**, *dwelling*). The modern meaning either originated as a phonetic loan or semantic extension (*expand one's dwelling* > *expand territory* > *to expel (enemies)* > *to reprimand* > *to blame*).

---

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: 宅] | [乙](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2256 [合集14206](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=14206&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 宅] | [尊](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_zun) [集成6014](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6014&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state)) [古幣](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty_coinage) | [image: 厇] | 81 古幣文編 |
| 戰國・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 厇] | 190 [包山楚簡](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%8C%85%E5%B1%B1%E6%A5%9A%E7%B0%A1) |
| 戰國・楚 簡 | [image: 㡯] | 109 望山楚簡1 |
| [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) 簡 | [image: 㡿] | 8.11 [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts) |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image] | 陰 魯峻碑 |
| 楷 | [image: 斥] |  |

<kbd>[image: 宅]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 宅]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 厇]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 厇]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 㡯]</kbd>

First, an internal sequence of developments in 「宅」 caused 「宀」 to sometimes be corrupted into 「厂」 or 「广」, forming 「厇」 or 「㡯」, respectively.

<kbd>[image: 㡿]</kbd>

Next, the inside was phonetically corrupted into 「屰」 (**/*ŋrak/**).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>
　
<kbd>[image: 斥]</kbd>

Further corruptions caused the shape to morph into something that looked identical to 「厈」, then eventually changing into 「斥」.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 1):

斥 has both components that have been corrupted over time. It comprises 广 and 屰.
广 is a roof, meaning home or building related, while 屰 is an upside-down 大, meaning reverse. When you expel or dismiss a person, you send them on the reverse direction and away from the building. 屰 is possibly a sound component as well.

Correct me if I am wrong, but blame is likely a borrowed meaning from the derived character 訴.

http://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%96%A5